# wp remove  query

Tags: query

i want to remove a certain query in wp 3.1

```
add_filter( 'query', 'remove_delete_7_day_draft_queries' ); 

function remove_delete_7_day_draft_queries( $query ) { 
    global $wpdb;
    $q = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'auto-draft' AND DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) > post_date";
    if ( $q == $query) {
        return false;
    }

    return $query; 
}
```

but in the error log i see something like this:
WordPress database error Query was empty for query  made by get_default_post_to_edit

any ideea how to remove the execution of the query without any error ?
tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about this piece of maintenance code right here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L419

Indeed, the code calls on lower level functionality of `$wpdb`, which doesn't contain too many hooks, only one in fact, `query`.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1061

So, in order to return an empty result set you'll have to come up with a no-operation type of query, here are some examples:

- `SELECT NULL;` (returns 1 NULL result)
- `DO 0;`
- `SET @ignore_me = 0;`
- `` SELECT * FROM `$wpdb->posts` WHERE 1=0; ``

Comment: tx , i'm going with SELECT * FROM `$wpdb->posts` WHERE 1=0;