# Remove the Homepage Query

Tags: loop, query, homepage

I have a homepage displaying the `home.php` template, containing 2 sidebars with widgets in them.

The main query still pulls in the standard 10 posts, but since I'm not displaying these, I'd like to eliminate the query being made to the database entirely. If needs be, an empty post loop will do as I am not using the main loop in my `home.php` template.

How would I do this? I could use `pre_get_posts` to minimise and reduce the query, but that still leaves me with a very fast query, how do I eliminate it entirely?

Comment: [This question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83187/recommended-way-to-drop-a-pending-query-in-pre-get-posts) seems to be worth reading. But if you asked me, I would use my own template and set it as static home page from settings, because while it would be possible, it's just not worth it. More interesting reading [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97811/how-to-prevent-execution-of-default-query-while-preserving-ability-to-use-wp-qu). Either all that or I completely missed the point of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The `posts_request` filter

Skimming through the `WP_Query` we find this part of interest:

```
if ( !$q['suppress_filters'] ) {
    /**
     * Filter the completed SQL query before sending.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param array    $request The complete SQL query.
     * @param WP_Query &$this   The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
     */
      $this->request = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_request', 
          array( $this->request, &$this ) );
   }

   if ( 'ids' == $q['fields'] ) {
       $this->posts = $wpdb->get_col( $this->request );
       $this->posts = array_map( 'intval', $this->posts );
       $this->post_count = count( $this->posts );
       $this->set_found_posts( $q, $limits );
       return $this->posts;
   }
```

We might try to eliminate the main home request through the `posts_request` filter. Here's an example:

```
add_filter( 'posts_request', function( $request, \WP_Query $q )
{
    // Target main home query
    if ( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() )
    {
        // Our early exit
        $q->set( 'fields', 'ids' );

        // No request
        $request = '';
    }

    return $request;    

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

where we force the `'fields' => 'ids'` for early exit.

### The `posts_pre_query` filter (WP 4.6+)

We could also use the new `posts_pre_query`<sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b8b7a008892718f135524dd635274f21a4da6c5b/wp-includes/query.php#L35593575)</sup> filter available in WordPress 4.6+

```
add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', function( $posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() )
    {
        $posts = [];
        $q->found_posts = 0;
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This filter makes it possible to skip the usual database queries to implement a custom posts injection instead.

I just tested this and noticed that this will not prevent sticky posts, opposite to the `posts_request` approach.

Check out the ticket [#36687](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36687) for more info and the [example there](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36687#comment:8) by @boonebgorges.

Comment: Very similar to what I just wrote, but I didn't spot the fields ids part, that knocked another 2 queries off, thanks!

Comment: ok great, sometimes it comes to mind how nice it would be to have an easy way to exit `WP_Query` early, e.g.  through an argument like  `'skip_query' => true` or even through a filter, but then I realise how easily that could mess up sites around the internet, in so many ways  ;-) @TomJNowell

Comment: There is a filter `split_the_query` just below the lines, do exactly the same but I wonder it does not reduce the number of  queries!

Comment: Great solution, even I missed `'fields' => 'ids'`, and I use it a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a neat trick I learned from @birgire, we can halt the main query by appending `AND where 0=1` to the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query. This might still result in one db query, but it will surely stop the main query from querying posts

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
    ) {
        $where .= ' AND where 0 = 1';
    }

    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You can also just try to replace the `WHERE` clause with `where 0 = 1`

```
$where = ' where 0 = 1';
```

instead of

```
$where .= ' AND where 0 = 1';
```

Unfortunately, I do not have time to test anything, but this should be a nice starting point

Comment: This sounds like it's the closest I can get to what I asked for, or at least, the most heavily optimised query, I'll consider this while investigating if the query itself can be eradicated

Comment: +1 for sharing this idea. But I tested it and it reduce the time by 2 ms :)

Comment: I wish I could remember where I learned it from, but this is also used by core  ;-) I think it would be nice to also ignore stickies `$q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true );` just in case.

Comment: @birgire Great spot. Even with my solution, you still get stickies back from the main query ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For reference, before: 45q, after: 42q

The code is very similar to the code used by @birgire

```
function _tomjn_home_cancel_query( $query, \WP_Query $q ) {
    if ( !$q->is_admin() && !$q->is_feed() && $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() ) {
        $query = false;
        $q->set( 'fields', 'ids' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', '_tomjn_home_cancel_query', 100, 2 );
```